# Monthly Builder base reset

Tags: clash-of-clans

Every month my builder base gets reset (downgraded) to 4000 points even if I am several hundred points above tha5 level (so far my max level is 4471) 
I have asked this question no less than 6 times on the settings contact us button but nobody ever answers and the question gets deleted
Does everyone get wiped out back to 4000 or if not how can you prevent it?
Thanks in advance for anyone’s help

Answer (score 1):

Clash of Clans, like many online multiplayer games, uses a "season" system where every month all players are reset to a baseline level based on their league. Everyone in Titan League or higher gets reset to 4000. There's no way to avoid this, and it happens to everyone.